# need an elegant way to find one match of hundreds without doing hundreds of queries

Tags: mysql, geospatial

Using MySQL 5.7 with geospatial extensions I have a table with field "poly" which defines the lateral bounds of a beam

I have a field "pt" which defines a single position.

To determine if a given point is in a given beam I run the query:

```
set @p=(select pt from beams where name='current_position');
SET @a = (select poly from beams where name='first_beam');
SELECT MBRWithin(@p,@a);
```

this returns "1" if the point is inside the polygon and "0" if not

but I have about 1000 beams, I want to find what beam the current_position is in, do I have to run a thousand queries or is there a way to elegantly return the beam that it is in? The beams do not overlap, there will be at most only 1 match.

Comment: I would start with something like this `set @p=(select pt from beams where name='current_position'); select name from beams where MBRWithin(@p,  poly);`

Answer (score 0):

MBRWithin can be used in a JOIN

```
SELECT p.id, a.id FROM 
    (select pt from beams where name='current_position') as p
INNER JOIN
    (select poly from beams where name='first_beam') as a
ON MBRWithin(p.pt, a.poly)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I did not realize MBRWithin can be used like that! This will be extremely useful.  Here is what I ended up with:         SELECT pt, poly FROM 
    (select pt from beams where name='current_position') as p
INNER JOIN
    (select poly from beams) as a
ON MBRWithin(pt,poly);